# How to use checkbox values in code?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

In my Oracle APEX application page I have checkbox item with multiple values. The source of checkbox is like this:

```
STATIC:One,Two,Apple
```

In page process I need to use the value from checkbox in PL/SQL code. As far as I understand I get colon separated values. Question is how to use those values and test if Value is `One`, then do this. If `Two` is checked as well, then do something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on situation you can use:
Convert string with delimiter to table (you can use this as subquery):

```
select regexp_substr('1:2:3','[^:]+', 1, level) ID from dual
connect by regexp_substr('1:2:3', '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null;

ID
--
 1
 2
 3
```

Check one value using `instr`:

```
where instr('1:2:3', '2') > 0
```

If value of the second argument of the function is contained inside the first argument - function returns its position, otherwise - 0.

Answer (score 0):

For performance I prefer the INSTR function, e.g. `INSTR(':'||:p_item||':',':Two:') > 0`